# Problem CKFinder with multilingual site

Tags: wysiwyg

I have installed the CKEditor module, the CKEditor library and the CKFinder library.
I have modified correctly the file config.php and the file settings.php, but when I want login in my site, I don't get the permission for access. If I comment the variable `cookie_domain` I can access at the site and all working properly, but I get a message error that say: "You are using a feature that requires $cookie_domain to be set, but it is not set in your settings.php file (CKFinder is enabled in the Advanced profile)". What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

set the $cookie_domain variable in sites/default/settings.php

```
<?php
$cookie_domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

Uncomment the `$base_url` variable and set the base URL of your website (without the trailing slash).

**Another option** if you have the Drupal Domain access module installed use

```
<?php
$base_domain = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
unset($base_domain[0]);
$base_domain = '.' . implode($base_domain, '.');

$cookie_domain = $base_domain;
?>
```

Here is the [reference](https://drupal.org/node/323170) to the answer

Comment: I have already uncomment the `$base_url` and I have set the base URL of my site. I'll try your option for the `$cookie_domain`